# How to compile or speed up a function with eigensystem?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, compile

I have defined two functions as following:

```
MapQ = Compile[{{r0, _Real, 2}, {r, _Real, 2}, xc, yc, {w, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{ M = ({
         {0., 0., 0., 0.},
         {0., 0., 0., 0.},
          {0., 0., 0., 0.},
          {0., 0., 0., 0.}
        }), x0, y0, z0, x, y, z, w1, w2, r2, c1, c2, c3, c4, x0x, y0y,
      z0z, sys, \[Theta], temp},
    Do[
     x0 = r0[[i, 1]] - xc; x = r[[i, 1]] - xc;
          y0 = r0[[i, 2]] - yc; y = r[[i, 2]] - yc;
        z0 = r0[[i, 3]]; z = r[[i, 3]];

     (*// matrix elements//*)
                 w1 = w[[i]];
     w2 = 2*w1;
     r2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x0^2 + y0^2 + z0^2;
     x0x = x0 x;
     y0y = y0 y;
     z0z = z0 z;
     c1 = (r2 - 2 (x0x + y0y + z0z));
     c2 = (r2 + 2 (-x0x + y0y + z0z));
     c3 = (r2 + 2 (x0x - y0y + z0z));
     c4 = (r2 + 2 (x0x + y0y - z0z));
     M[[1, 1]] += w1 c1;
     M[[1, 2]] += w2 (y z0 - z y0);
     M[[1, 3]] += w2 (-x z0 + z x0);
     M[[1, 4]] += w2 (x y0 - y x0);
     M[[2, 2]] += w1 c2;
     M[[2, 3]] -= w2 (x y0 + y x0);
     M[[2, 4]] -= w2 (x z0 + z x0);
     M[[3, 3]] += w1 c3;
     M[[3, 4]] -= w2 (y z0 + z y0);
     M[[4, 4]] += w1 c4;

     , {i, Length[r0]}];
    M = ({
       {M[[1, 1]], M[[1, 2]], M[[1, 3]], M[[1, 4]]},
       {M[[1, 2]], M[[2, 2]], M[[2, 3]], M[[2, 4]]},
       {M[[1, 3]], M[[2, 3]], M[[3, 3]], M[[3, 4]]},
       {M[[1, 4]], M[[2, 4]], M[[3, 4]], M[[4, 4]]}
      })

    ], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];



AngleQ[M_] := Block[{sys, \[Theta]},
       sys = Eigensystem[M];
  If[sys[[2, 4, 1]] < 0, sys[[2, 4]] = -sys[[2, 4]], None];
       sys[[2, 4]] = Normalize[sys[[2, 4]]];
  \[Theta] = 2 ArcCos[sys[[2, 4, 1]]];
  If[sys[[2, 4, 4]]/Sin[\[Theta]/2] < 0, \[Theta] = -\[Theta], None];
  \[Theta]
  ]
```

[image]
The first function can be compiled to generate C-code and parallelizable.

My question is that how to combine these two functions together and speed up eventually?

Since **Compile** does not allow me to put **Eigensystem** inside to optimize, any suggestion?

Many thanks!

**Update**

In particular, I want to map this to a set of inputs. As in the following:
My question is how can I parallelize this map? I try ParallelMap but it seems not work.
[image]

Input file can be download from here:

[r.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L-i6WaWv1Lz7iN4tFfU1Ut288vEZdYo4)

[r0.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14zm65f6MReCA3httb_w7hCNlEL5_WyfQ/view?usp=sharing)

[w.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_TYIomBo05VoP8Z8FFO3E4Be464C-HsL/view?usp=sharing)

xc1:24.2

yc1:31.37

Comment: Btw.: Questions about code without example data or a usage example are hard to answer. Please keep that in mind when you post here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my attempt on the function `MapQ`.

## The modified code

```
MapQ2 = Compile[{{r0, _Real, 2}, {r, _Real, 2}, xc, yc, {w, _Real, 1}}, 
   Block[{M11, M12, M13, M14, M22, M23, M24, M33, M34, M44, x0, y0, z0, x, y, z, w1, w2, r2, c1, c2, c3, c4, x0x, y0y, z0z},
    M11 = M12 = M13 = M14 = M22 = M23 = M24 = M33 = M34 = M44 = 0.;
    Do[
     x0 = Compile`GetElement[r0, i, 1] - xc;
     x = Compile`GetElement[r, i, 1] - xc;
     y0 = Compile`GetElement[r0, i, 2] - yc;
     y = Compile`GetElement[r, i, 2] - yc;
     z0 = Compile`GetElement[r0, i, 3];
     z = Compile`GetElement[r, i, 3];
     (*//matrix elements//*)

     w1 = Compile`GetElement[w, i];
     w2 = 2. w1;
     r2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x0^2 + y0^2 + z0^2;
     x0x = x0 x;
     y0y = y0 y;
     z0z = z0 z;
     c1 = (r2 - 2. (x0x + y0y + z0z));
     c2 = (r2 + 2. (-x0x + y0y + z0z));
     c3 = (r2 + 2. (x0x - y0y + z0z));
     c4 = (r2 + 2. (x0x + y0y - z0z));
     M11 += w1 c1;
     M12 += w2 (y z0 - z y0);
     M13 += w2 (-x z0 + z x0);
     M14 += w2 (x y0 - y x0);
     M22 += w1 c2;
     M23 -= w2 (x y0 + y x0);
     M24 -= w2 (x z0 + z x0);
     M33 += w1 c3;
     M34 -= w2 (y z0 + z y0);
     M44 += w1 c4;
     , {i, Length[r0]}];
    {
     {M11, M12, M13, M14},
     {M12, M22, M23, M24},
     {M13, M23, M33, M34},
     {M14, M24, M34, M44}
     }
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

## Timing example and test

```
n = 100000;
r0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
r = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
w = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];

aa = MapQ[r, r0, 0., 0., w]; // RepeatedTiming // First
bb = MapQ2[r, r0, 0., 0., w]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[aa - bb]]
```

> 0.014
>
> 0.00092
>
> 0.

So this generates exactly the same result, but 15 times faster.

## Crucial changes

- Storing the entries of the upper triangle matrix of `M` in scalar *registers*; these are faster to access than an array, because every access operation )read or write) into an array with `Part` in *Mathematica* will put a bound-check into the C code. For read operations, this can be mended by `` Compile`GetElement ``, but I do not know of a way to do the same for write operations. And the frequently used `+=` and `-=` are both read and write operations. This is why using real registers during the computations and building the matrix only in the end is so much faster.
- As noted above, I replaced a few occurences of `Part` by `` Compile`GetElement ``. In order to ake this effective, one has to add the option `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`; only then the creation of C-code for the bound checking will be deactivated.
- I replaced a few occurences of integer `2` by `2.`; otherwise one has a few needless runtime type-casts. Does not make a big difference in this case, though.

As it turns out, the `Eigensystem` is not the bottleneck here. `Eigensystem` effectlively calls a compiled library and cannot be sped up with `Compile` any further. Which does not meen that it were impossible to write a more efficient function that is dedicated to compute solely 4D eigensystems. In principle, that might be possible because polynomials of order 4 can be solved algebraically in closed form. But I would try that only if `Eigensystem` consitutes more than, say, 30% of your final running time. And even then I would have to think about how worthwhile this investment of programming time would be.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Now I want to proceed further. To parallelize a lot of similar simulation. Could you see the original post?

Comment: Could you please post example input data?

Comment: It would be interesting to have some kind of simple `Compile` optimizer that does things like register unwrapping whenever it sees that a given matrix variable is only ever accessed by explicit indices.

Comment: @b3m2a1 True. I am also not convinced that the unwrapping of loop constructs done by _Mathematica_  in the creation of C code is for the better. Modern C compilers should be able to vectorize `for`-loops, but I do not know if they can optimize these `goto` mess produced by _Mathematica_... oO

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher if this were not WRI we're talking about, I'd imagine the new compiler could be able to make better use of modern compiler tech once it matures more. Since this is WRI...maybe there's like a 50% chance this happens.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I upload the input files. Now you can import them to your nb.